# How do I remove the y-axis title in R for plot_ly?

Tags: plotly

I would like to remove the y-axis title for plot_ly in R, but I can't find any suggestions on how to do this.

If I specify a blank axis title, it generates an automatic title.

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting the axis titles to an empty string ('' or "") works:

```
library(plotly)

# Calculate average mpg for each number of cylinders
agg_data <- aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, mean)

# Create bar chart
fig <- plot_ly(data = agg_data, x = ~cyl, y = ~mpg, type = 'bar') %>%
  layout(title = 'Average MPG by Number of Cylinders',
         xaxis = list(title = ''),
         yaxis = list(title = ''))

# Display the plot
fig
```

But setting `title = NULL` results in plotly returning the default title like the OP describes.

Answer (score -1):

In `plot_ly`, you can use the `layout` function to customize the layout of the plot, including the axis titles. To remove the y-axis title, you can set the `title` attribute of the y-axis to an empty string. Here's an example:

```
library(plotly)

# Sample data
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(10, 14, 18, 24, 30)

# Create a basic plot_ly plot
plot <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers')

# Customize the layout to remove the y-axis title
plot <- plot %>% layout(
  yaxis = list(title = "")
)

# Display the plot
plot
```

In this example, the `layout` function is used to customize the y-axis (`yaxis`). The `title` attribute is set to an empty string (`""`), which effectively removes the y-axis title.

Make sure to replace the sample data (`x` and `y`) with your actual data.